# Reading 2D Array from a text file, HELP!

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

UPDATE: I realized that the issue was I was using print instead of echo to print the data, so it was showing the array instead of the data within it. Thanks a ton guys!

I currently have a text file that looks like this:

```
0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0
```

And I'm using this function:

```
function rFile($fileName){
$resultF = fopen($fileName, "r") or die("can't open file");
$array = array(); //Create the first dimension of a 2D array
$i=0;
while(!feof($resultF)){
  $line = fgets($resultF);
  $line = trim($line, "\n");
  $tokens = explode(",",$line);
  $array[$i]=array(); //Create the second dimension of the 2D array
  $tokenCount = sizeof($tokens);
  for($j=0; $j<$tokenCount; $j++){
    $array[$i][$j] = $tokens[$j];
  }
  $i++;
 }
return $array;
  }
```

Essentially, it's supposed to read through the file, explode each "0" and store it in a 2D array, $array. For some reason it returns this:

```
Array[0]
Array[1]
Array[2]
....etc etc
```

Anyone know what I did wrong?

Comment: If you found your answer then accept an answer or answer it yourself and accept it.

Comment: You can replace the whole function with just `$array = array_map("str_getcsv", file($fileName));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going about it the hard way, by using for loops and counters.  By using PHP's `$array[] = $val` append syntax, you can save a lot of effort here.

```
// all the file handling code...

while(!feof($resultF)){
  $line = fgets($resultF);
  $line = trim($line, "\n");
  $tokens = explode(",",$line);

  // Append the line array.
  $array[] = $tokens; //Create the second dimension of the 2D array
}

return $array;
```

Or to be even more concise:

```
$array[] = explode(",",$line);
```

Comment: Even when I do it this way, the output still gives me Array[0]...Array[4] instead of just the value 0

Answer (score 2):

PHP multi-dimensional arrays are just arrays of arrays. There's no need for the inner loop. You can just do

```
while(...) {
   ... fgets stuff
   $array[$i] = explode(',', $line);
   $i++;
}
```

and get the same effect.

Comment: Try `print_r(explode(',', $line))` to see if your data's actually exploding right. As well, try `print_r($line)` by itself to see what you're actually reading.

Comment: When I do print_r(explode(',', $line)), I get this:
Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 0 [2] => 0 [3] => 0 [4] => 0 ) 
Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 0 [2] => 0 [3] => 0 [4] => 0 ) 
Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 0 [2] => 0 [3] => 0 [4] => 0 ) 
Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 0 [2] => 0 [3] => 0 [4] => 0 ) 
Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 0 [2] => 0 [3] => 0 [4] => 0 ) 
Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 0 [2] => 0 [3] => 0 [4] => 0 ) 
Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 0 [2] => 0 [3] => 0 [4] => 0 ) 
Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 0 [2] => 0 [3] => 0 [4] => 0 )

Comment: But it should be just a bunch of 0's...this boggles my mind lol

Comment: @fullOfQuestions `print_r` is a diagnostic tool.  It shows the array's structure, rather than just dumping out its values. To see only the values (bunch of 0's) you would have to write nested `foreach` loops to echo out each one.

Comment: It is a bunch of zeroes, each with a unique index going from 0->4

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
function rFile($filename) {
    $lines = file($filename);

    if ($lines !== false) {
        foreach ($lines as & $line) {
            $line = explode(',', trim($line, '\n\r'));           
        }
    }

    return $lines;
}
```

Comment: Hmm I get the same result. I'm calling the function on the text file, and having it loop and output each element and it's still printing that way

Comment: I presume your END_OF_LINE character might be problematic then, as PHP seems to read your entire file into a single line.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, since this is comma delimitated, we can use [fgetcsv](http://us.php.net/fgetcsv) to make this short and simple:

```
$file = fopen('test.txt', 'r');

$matrix = array();
while($entries = fgetcsv($file)) {
  $matrix[] = $entries;
}

fclose($file);
```

Resulting array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 0
            [2] => 0
            [3] => 0
            [4] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 0
            [2] => 0
            [3] => 0
            [4] => 0
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 0
            [2] => 0
            [3] => 0
            [4] => 0
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 0
            [2] => 0
            [3] => 0
            [4] => 0
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 0
            [2] => 0
            [3] => 0
            [4] => 0
        )

)
```

Comment: But Even when I do it this way, the output still gives me Array[0]...Array[4] instead of just the value 0

Comment: @fullOfQuestions What are you expecting it to give? If you want the first element it's `$matrix[0][0]`, which is `0`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$f = file($fileName);

$results = array();

foreach ($f as $line) {
    $line = preg_replace("\n", "", $line);
    $results[] = explode(",", $line);
}
```